# Azure FHIR Service unable to recognize derived extensions and generates a warning

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I created a FHIR Patient profile, which is based on FHIR US Core 6.1.0.
The profile is created with FHIR ShortHand and converted to FHIR JSON format with "sushi" with the inclusion of a snapshot:
`sushi build -s .`

After publishing the profile to Azure Health Data FHIR Service, I'm trying to validate a Patient resource based on the created profile.
However, Azure FHIR Service generates a warning that the service is unable to derive an extension from the US Core Patient profile:

```
curl -X post --header "Content-type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer ${azFhirToken}" --data "@fsh-generated/resources/PatientUS.json" 'https://abc-fhir001.fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient/$validate' | jq
                                                                        
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6523    0   605  100  5918    354   3466  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3834

{
  "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
  "issue": [
    {
      "severity": "warning",
      "code": "business-rule",
      "details": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/dotnet-api-operation-outcome",
            "code": "2012"
          }
        ],
        "text": "Cannot walk into unknown StructureDefinition with canonical 'http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race' at 'https://abc-fhir001.fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com/StructureDefinition/patient-us#Patient.extension (Patient.extension:race)'"
      },
      "location": [
        "Patient // OperationOutcome.Location is deprecated, please use OperationOutcome.Expression"
      ],
      "expression": [
        "Patient"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My question in general is - how can I overcome this warning?
Is there a way to make Azure FHIR Service retrieve and analyze extensions (race, etnicity, etc) from http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-patient ?
Probably there is some trick to include race/enticity/etc US Core extensions into my Patient profile before publishing it?
In worst case, can I suppress the warning?